# Does TDS know to delete items with delta packages?

Tags: tds

When using TDS to create delta packages for deployment does it know to delete items? It would appear that items which are deleted in the project aren't included in the delta package.

UPDATE:

Just to clarify using the [child sync options](http://www.hhog.com/blog/tds-how-to-delete-items-target-sitecore-instance-tds-update-package/) isn't a solution in this case. The items being deleted reside under the `/sitecore/content/Applications` item in the `Core` database.

Comment: I wasn't aware TDS did delta packages; I thought that it just created entire packages of whatever was checked in.  Am I mistaken, or are you using something other than TDS to generate the packages from the item files?

Comment: TDS 5.5 provides this functionality based on a date in the past (http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/TDS-5-5)

Comment: Since you can't use child sync options, I believe you would have the same issue even with "normal" packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delta packages are different from normal packages in only one way: instead of including all project items, they include only items that were changed after a certain date. Whether or not an item has changed is determined by taking the value of every item's `__Updated` field and comparing it to the date/time you set [in TDS project settings](https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/propgeneral#DeployItemsChangedAfter).

When generating packages, TDS also includes deployment property 'metadata' from ALL items in the project (whether they're included by Delta Packages or not). That metadata tells the update package installer, how to add/remove/update any set of items.
If an item was removed at some point, then the package won't contain it, however the package may contain it's parent, and the ChildSync deployment property metadata for that.

Therefore, if your project had the parent item, with child sync on, and you deleted that child item from your project, it will be deleted with the install of the package.
For Delta Packages, this remains the same, even without the parent being part of the delta package (i.e even if itself wasn't updated itself since the delta date that's been set).

So to the title of this question, YES, Delta packages can delete items, the exact same way complete packages generated by TDS can delete items.
To directly answer the bulk of your question: no, without being able to set the child sync options, update packages (delta or complete) can not delete items.The [recursive deploy action](https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds/propbuild#RecursiveDeployAction) along with ChildSync is needed for that.

Comment: As I suspected Dymtro, marked as answer. I shall ask another question regarding how to solve this :)!

Comment: This isn't a limitation of just delta packages though, right? TDS in general can't do deletions outside of recursive deploy action / child sync settings, right?

Comment: @techphoria414 Correct.